# como soluciono el error ReflectionException in Route.php line 333

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy usando laravel 5.3 y todo estaba bien hasta que intente crear un nuevo metodo en mi controlador, me dice que no existe apesar de que esta ahí si pongo el metodo en otro controlador si funciona estas son mis rutas

```
Route::get('/', function () {

return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();


Route::get('auth/google', 'GoogleController@redirectToProvider')->name('google.login');
Route::get('auth/google/callback', 'GoogleController@handleProviderCallback');
Route::get('/mapa', 'MapaController@index');
Route::post('/video', 'VideosController@subirvideo');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
Route::get('/registra', 'HomeController@registra');
Route::post('/registro', 'HomeController@registro');
Route::post('/actualizae', 'HomeController@actualiza_estado');
Route::post('/actualizamail', 'HomeController@actualiza_correo');
Route::post('/elimina', 'HomeController@elimina_usuario');
Route::get('/mapaadmin', 'HomeController@probando');
});
```

todas funcionan a excepcion de la última @probando

el código del controlador es el siguiente:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Socialite;
use Auth;
use App\User;
use DB;
use Alert;


class HomeController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{

    $this->middleware('admin');
}


public function index()
{
    return view('/');
}


public function reigstra()
{
    $estados=DB::table('estados')->get();

    $usuarios = DB::table('users')->paginate(10);

    return view('register', ['estados' => $estados], ['usuarios' => $usuarios]);
}

public function probando()
{
  return view('/');
}

public function actualiza_estado()
{

  DB::table('users')
    ->where('email', $_POST['userid'])
    ->update(['id_estado' => $_POST['id_estado']]);


}

public function elimina_usuario()
{
  DB::table('users')->where('id', $_POST['id'])->delete();


}

public function actualiza_correo()
{

  DB::table('users')
    ->where('id', $_POST['id'])
    ->update(['email' => $_POST['correo']]);


}

public function registro()
{


  $revisacorreo=DB::table('users')->where('email','=',$_POST['email'])->value('email');

  if($_POST['email']==$revisacorreo)
  {
    Alert::error('El usuario '.$_POST['email'].' ya se encuentra dado de alta', 'Imposible dar de alta')->persistent('Cerrar');
    return back();
  }

  else{
    DB::table('users')->insert(['email' => $_POST['email'], 'id_estado' => $_POST['estado']]);

    Alert::success('El usuario '.$_POST['email'].' fue dado de alta', 'Usuario creado con exito')->persistent('Cerrar');
    return back();

  }
}
```

}
pero me manda el siguiente error

ReflectionException in Route.php line 333: 
Method App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::probando() does not exist

ayuda por favor

Comment: Mmm.. estoy viendo q no tienes el código tal cual lo usas tu, podrías colocar tu código sin ediciones?

Comment: q URL estás intentando ejecutar? Debe ser ser /mapaadmin

Comment: la url que intento entrar es http://adcopath.ilce.edu.mx/mapaadmin, como te menciono el resto de rutas si entran pero esta no, el metodo probando lo deje en blanco por que ponga lo que ponga es el mismo error, el resto del codigo es el resto que pone laravel y otras rutas pero ahorita lo edito para ponerlo completo

Comment: que no el `return view('/');` debe de contener el nombre del blade de tus vista?